# Laravel show data from key column not from id

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have this route:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
Route::get('articles/aukcija/{key}', 'ArticlesController@aukcija');
```

and I have this function in Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Auth::user()->articles()->findOrFail($id);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }

    public function aukcija($key)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($key);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }
```

I need both of them... but how I can get Article with token stored in key column instead ID...

so when I write `localhost:8888/article/1` and `localhost:8888/article/aukcija/f4576ceusyfc674wr873cr48c7sefc` to get the same article becouse article with ID=1 have key=f4576ceusyfc674wr873cr48c7sefc...

Comment: is this work correctly?

Comment: just for show function , for function aukcija this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public function aukcija($key)
{
    $article = Article::where('key', $key)->firstOrFail();

    // or
    $article = Article::where(compact('key'))->firstOrFail();

    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}
```